# Reading mails via EWS Managed API withoug passwords

Tags: c#, email, passwords, exchangewebservices

I've just started to use Exchange web service managed API in C#. I got a peculiar requirement to read emails from a exchange server using a user id. As per our admin, password is not needed for this. I've searched many sites, but in every site, they write about connecting with password. Can some one please help me how to connect without password? I am using following code to connect:

```
Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("username@domain.com");
ExchangeService service = new 
ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);            
service.PreAuthenticate = true;            
service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@domain.com");
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("userid", string.Empty);            
      FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb);
```

Thanks in Advance,
Aswin

Comment: Try not to set the `Credentials` property.

Comment: I've tried. Exception- "credentials are required to make a request"

Comment: Try to net set the `PreAuthenticate` also

Comment: Set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `true` before you invoke `AutodiscoverUrl`

Comment: I tried both. Setting Defaultcredentials to true takes my credentials. So, it didn't work. The service mail should be used with different userid, for which password is not provided.